# Linq: TPT hierarchy, performance of finding rows of multiple subtypes

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework

My situation is:
I have a database where I did choose to implement a TPT hierarchy. I have therefore one base class and about 25 subclasses.
I have to query this hierarchy to get all the rows of only 5 of the subtypes.
My first shot was to make 5 different queries of this type:

```
db.Rows.OfType<SubClass1>()...
```

I'm testing locally with the database in Azure, and each of this queries takes about 250ms to complete.
Having more than one second of gross time, I thought about optimizing this part, trying to make one only trip to the db, so I tried writing something like:

```
db.Rows.Where(r => r is SubClass1 || r is SubClass2)...
```

Executing this new query, I obtain the right result (I made the real test), but the executing time is over 6 seconds!
I fired up the logger in Visual Studio debugger, for the DbContext, and I can see that the resulting SQL query is over 1350 lines of code (I don't put it in this message, but if someone wants to see it, I'm here...)
Moreover, I'm not an expert in SQL, but the query is unreadable enough, as you can imagine for a query of 1350 lines of code...
What can it be, and what can I do, to improve my query time?
Thanks in advance.
Andrea

Comment: TPH would be far more efficient, but then the classes shouldn't differ too much...

Comment: Do you see the slow query always or only on first run? Sometimes EF gets dizzy and takes a lot of time to compile the query to SQL. But the query is cached so the next calls should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks it might be the TPT mapping itself.

The issue is that a query against the base type forces EF to discover the C# type that each database row must be materialized into. The query must join each subtype to the base table then test the row for the presence of the columns that determine a C# type. With a large class hierarchy a query against the base type will result in a highly complex query, like the one you seeing. Read this article, http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt, for an in depth explanation of how query generation for TPT works.

As for improving performance, the above article suggests;

> For ad hoc reporting, database views provide a way to offset the complexity of the TPT strategy. A view may be used to transform the table-per-type model into the much simpler table-per-hierarchy model.

Comment: Thanks, Luke, you are convincing me, and for this I will choose your answer (the only one, for now! :-)) as THE answer. What worries me is the large number of fields I'll end up with, with 25 subclasses, with TPH. I'll give it a try, and report here whatever results I get...

Comment: Luke, you are NOT convincing me anymore! :-) I hope to not hurt you, I'm a little bit joking, but you can read below why...